Equivalent circuits
I'm wondering if my use of the transformation principle (transforming a current source into a tension source) is valid here?

Knowing that a current source in parallel to a resistor can be transformed into a voltage source with that same resistor in series. I took the current source and R_1 and supposed it was just a current source (I'm not sure I'm allowed to do that, in all the Thevenin equivalences I've seen it's always a current source alone and never in series with anything else) that are in parallel to R_2 and transformed R_1 and the current source into R__1 and a tension source in series with R_2.
As I'm typing it, I think it's wrong, but let's see...

No, it's not even a little bit correct and, without values for the current source, it's not easy to explain this to you. Do you have a relevant book you can read? I'm sure it's also covered on line.

Note that in English, "tension" means something entirely different. Only the word "voltage" is used to refer to that quantity, outside of a handful of archaic uses.

A resistor in series with a perfect current source will have no effect on the remainder of the circuit. It can be replaced with a short.
So, replace R1 in the right circuit with a wire and it will be correct.
You don't have this case in your circuit, but a resistor in parallel with a perfect voltage source will have no effect on the remainder of the circuit. It can be removed.
